# How to use the context menu of the parent in a textbox

Tags: wpf, textbox, listbox, contextmenu, parent

I have a listbox with several controls. Each control contains an custom autocompletebox which contains a System.Windows.Controls.AutoCompleteBox. When I right click on the control a custom contextm menu shows up. But with a right click on the textbox there appears the default contextmenu of the TextBox (with Copy, Cut and Paste).

My goal is to show my custom context menu with a right click on the TextBox.

Further informations: 
My custom context menu is defined in the DataTemplate of the ListBox but I could define it in the Ressources or somewhere else as well.

I tried: 
- when I null the context menu of the custom autocompletebox or the System.Windows.Controls.AutoCompleteBox of it, there is no effect at all

Thanks for every help ;)

Comment: Can you show your current XAML/code

Answer (score 1):

You can either bind the context menu property to parent element's context menu or bind to the context menu once you define in the resource.xaml

Answer (score 0):

Try using PreviewMouseDown instead of MouseDown to handle the MouseDown event.

In XAML:

```
<ListBox Margin="3" PreviewMouseDown="MouseDownOnListBox">
```

In Code:

```
    private void MouseDownOnListBox(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
        {
            //Display your context menu
        }
    }
```

If you are using PreviewMouseDown on a list, when you click anywhere on the list, this event will be triggered first.